# I want to add last modified date and time to this powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

```
Get-Childitem -path \\lettertext\BIZ -Recurse -Include *.txt |
ForEach-Object {
    $Parts = $_.fullname.split('\')[4..7]
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Customer = $Parts[0]
        ClientGroup = $Parts[1]
        Client = $Parts[2]
        ClientDivision = $Parts[3]
        FileName = $_.FullName | Split-Path -Leaf


    }
} | Export-Csv c:\Letters\BIZ.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The code above gives me the text files in the different folders but I want to also add the last modification date and time.. Thanks

Comment: you can expose the properties/methods of what Get-ChildItem returns with 'get-childitem|get-member`

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
Get-Childitem -path \\lettertext\BIZ -Recurse -Include *.txt |
ForEach-Object {
    $Parts = $_.fullname.split('\')[4..7]
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Customer = $Parts[0]
        ClientGroup = $Parts[1]
        Client = $Parts[2]
        ClientDivision = $Parts[3]
        FileName =  $_.FullName | Split-Path -Leaf
        LastModifiedDate= $_.LastWriteTime  
        #| Split-Path -Leaf 


    }
} | Export-Csv c:\Letters\BIZ.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I added this and it worked and I was able to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

try this. you can remove the lines you don't want

```
Get-Childitem -path \\lettertext\BIZ -Recurse -Include *.txt |
ForEach-Object {
    $Parts = $_.fullname.split('\')[4..7]
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Customer = $Parts[0]
        ClientGroup = $Parts[1]
        Client = $Parts[2]
        ClientDivision = $Parts[3]
        FileName = $_.name
        CreationTime = $_.CreationTime
        CreationTimeUtc = $_.CreationTimeUtc
        LastAccessTime = $_.LastAccessTime
        LastAccessTimeUtc = $_.LastAccessTimeUtc
        LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
        LastWriteTimeUtc = $_.LastWriteTimeUtc
    }
} | Export-Csv c:\Letters\BIZ.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This can do it though; it adds more detail to it,